# Why AWS Neptune is not supporting MetaProperties feature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Why AWS Neptune is not supporting the `MetaProperties` feature?  It's a very useful feature in gremlin. Will it support the upcoming release?

Usecase 1:

Girl Name usually change from time to time, birth name will have her dad family name after marriage husband surname. It will be easy, if we have `start_date_time & end_date_time`  metaproperties on `name` properties. To get current name and to maintain history as well.

Usecase 2:

The above use case is also applicable on street name, city/town, state and even for country.

If we update, we lose the data. If we use `cardinality` we can't tell when to when the `name` was used without metadata.

Use case 3:

`Expiry dates` we can attach to the some of properties

......
and many more...
......

Ofcourse, all of these usecases are possible to implement without metaproperties but it will be lot easier, if we have metaproperites features

Comment: Could you please say a bit more about the use cases where you need meta properties? I'm familiar with a few but it would be helpful to hear about the ways you might use the feature.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence added few use cases